# I can't setup bind9

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

where is my problem?
I'm trying to find problem for 4 days I'm losing my sanity.

```
 ;
; BIND data file for starmc.ir
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     starmc.ir. root.starmc.ir. (
                             24         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
starmc.ir. IN NS ns1.starmc.ir.
starmc.ir. IN NS ns2.starmc.ir.
5.61.28.43 IN NS ns1.starmc.ir.
@ IN A 5.61.28.43
@ IN NS  ns1.starmc.ir.
ns. IN A 5.61.28.43
ns1 IN A 5.61.28.43
ns2 IN A 5.61.28.43
www IN A 5.61.28.43
```

Comment: You don't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: `5.61.28.43 IN NS ns1.starmc.ir.` makes no sense. Or certainly not what you think it does, because left name is `5.61.28.43.starmc.ir.` in fact. `ns. IN A 5.61.28.43` is also outside of the zone (because of trailing dot) hence invalid in that zonefile.

Comment: Congrats ! It works !

Answer (score 0):

Try more simply with :

```
;
; BIND data file for starmc.ir
;
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     ns1.starmc.ir. root.starmc.ir. (
                     2022071401         ; Serial
                          28800         ; Refresh
                           7200         ; Retry
                         604800         ; Expire
                          86400 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
starmc.ir. IN NS ns1.starmc.ir.
ns1 IN A 5.61.28.43
www 14400 A 5.61.28.43
```

ns2 is not define because it doesn't exist by whois.nic.ir , so I think it's useless (nic.ir is responsible of NS advertisement). If it's assigned to the same IP, it's also useless.
Be very careful with syntax, specially with trailing dots.

**I edited my answer (a faulty MNAME !)**

and I don't like

> `@       IN      SOA     ns1.starmc.ir. root.starmc.ir. (`

root.starmc.ir. is an email address, in fact, and I prefer dns@domain.tld. Note that the address should exist.

`@       IN      SOA     ns1.starmc.ir. dns.starmc.ir. (`

**I edited my answer (testing)**

Do your tests from the outside of your LAN (you'll adjust this part after). for example, use a laptop tethering to a 4G phone...

As things can change very slowly with DNS, adapt TTL to a very short value, 600 or 3600 (seconds) for testing. Don't forget to increment Serial at each change. Don't forget to get back to a 'normal' value afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Check your zonefile by `named-checkzone` (Ubuntu package `bind9-utils`):

```
named-checkzone mydomain.com db.mydomain-zonefile
```